# About Magento2 backend form button "Save", "SaveAndContinue"

Tags: magento2, backend

To create a backend form via ui_component, I define following in the config file to display buttons **save** and **saveAndContinue** Button

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="save" xsi:type="string">namespace\module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton</item>
    <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">namespace\module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
</item>
```

Respectively, two files `SaveButton.php` and `SaveAndContinueButton.php` are created and both implement `ButtonProviderInterface`

As I know, button is mainly rendered from a `getButtonData` function. See `SaveAndContinueButton.php`

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    $TodoItemId = $this->getTodoItemId();
    $data = [];
    if ($TodoItemId) {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit'],
                ],
            ],
            'sort_order' => 80,
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The `data_attribute` is where that I don't understand. How does it know which file to handle save request?

If we check the `SaveButton.php`, We saw

```
$data = [
    'label' => __('Save TodoItem'),
    'class' => 'save primary',
    'data_attribute' => [
        'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
        'form-role' => 'save',
    ],
    'sort_order' => 90,
];
```

I know in the ui_component config file, there is

```
<item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="path/to/save"/>
```

Both action successfully execute same `Save.php` file and it makes sense. What confuse me much is `data_attribute` and how does `SaveAndContinueButton`  pass parameter "`back`" so that it knows to stay at the same page instead of go to grid (normally grid is entry point of a form, aka edit page).

If we take another look at the `deleteButton`, it's another landscape

```
$data = [
    'label' => __('Delete'),
    'class' => 'delete',
    'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
        'Are you sure you want to do this?'
    ) . '\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',

    'sort_order' => 20,
];
```

It directly executes the onClick JavaScript event. Any idea/suggestion will be appreciated. thanks

One more question: what's the different of `data_attribute` and `on_click`? or advantage one over another one?

Comment: I have save and continue , but it redirects to magento admin page not found error

Comment: What are the files needed to add save and continue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have a full explanation, but I have an idea.
All elements rendered with `mage-init` will/should be handled by some javascript code.
You are linking these buttons to a form, and the form is handled by this js file `lib/web/mage/backend/form.js` where a jquery ui widget is created.

These are the options for the widget

```
options: {
    handlersData: {
        save: {},
        saveAndContinueEdit: {
            action: {
                args: {
                    back: 'edit'
                }
            }
        },
        preview: {
            target: '_blank'
        }
    }
},
```

you can see a `saveAndContinueEdit` in there somewhere inside `handlersData`.
Looking for the usages of `handlersData`  you end up in `_beforeSubmit` where some magic happens (I don't really understand everything in there), and at one point `_processData` is called.
Moving to `_processData` you will see something like this

```
if (attrName === 'action') {
    data[attrName] = this._getActionUrl(attrValue);
}
```

this means that the `action` of the form is changed based on the button pressed.

the `_getActionUrl` function looks like this

```
_getActionUrl: function(data) {
    if ($.type(data) === 'object') {
        return this._buildURL(this.oldAttributes.action, data.args);
    } else {
        return $.type(data) === 'string' ? data : this.oldAttributes.action;
    }
},
```

you can see in there `data.args` involved.  The same variable in the widget options for `saveAndContinueEdit`.

Conclusion: When you set the role `saveAndContinueEdit` toa  submit button, the action of the form is changed via js and `back/edit` is added to the url.

`on_click` is transformed to the `onclick` event and simply called.
I honestly have no idea why there are 2 ways of doing this. Maybe the `delete` actions didn't get refactored yet.