# Magento2 : How to add button in admin custom module page?

Tags: magento2, admin, xml, action, custom-button

I want to add one button here

how I can add code??

and how to add action **controller**

[image: Admin custom page]
any idea ??

i already tried this answer(https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212656/73525)  but showing 
error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>            must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/equpo2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 206 and defined in 
>           /var/www/html/equpo2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 172

Comment: You can follow the this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212655/how-to-add-save-and-continue-button-in-ui-form-in-magento-2

Comment: But it's not showing for me

Comment: Show your code how you've tried.

Comment: i first created shows like the first comment (link)




uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/equpo2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 206 and defined in /var/www/html/equpo2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 172

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212656/73525

this answers

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related but having spent best part of 2 days wrestling with this error, finally figured it out by debugging the Magento core. Hopefully this will help someone else encountering this error.

```
uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given
```

Basically this error means it can't find the ui component XML file. I know, instead of just crashing with a error that means nothing, why not report that it can't find the XML for the component in question? That's just laziness.

Why didn't it find it? Because the module root view folder is named "view" and not "View". Some module root folders are capitalised others not. Why the inconsistency?

But then this issue goes back to Linus Torvolds who should not have made file/folder names case sensitive. Where's the value in making MyFolder different to myfolder!?! Probably more an oversight than an informed decision.