How save button run in code

my ui form

my button config
when i f12 network, i saw it send post request to save controller,but i dont know how it works

i found similar question here and the first guy who explain it look good https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128054/about-magento2-backend-form-button-save-saveandcontinue
